# Problema no cadastro de um item

Tags: php

Olá esta acontecendo um erro onde ele não retorna para a pagina definida, mas na url aparece que ele entro na pagina controleProduto que foi definida. A página simplesmente fica branca.

Esse é o formulario.

```
<form class="" method="post" action="controleProduto.php">
        <h1 class="">
          <b>Adicione Produtos</b>
        </h1>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="nome">
            <b>Nome:</b>
          </label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome do Produto" id="nome" name="nome"> </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="valor">
            <b>Valor:</b>
          </label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="valor" name="valor" placeholder="Valor do produto" > 
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="opcao" id="Cadastrar">Confirmar
        </button>
        <a href="paginaSessao.php" class="btn btn-light">
          <b>Voltar</b>
        </a>
      </form>
```

Esse é o arquivo chamado depois do formulario."controleProduto".

```
include 'crudProduto.php';

if(isset($_POST["opcao"])){

$opcao = $_POST["opcao"];

if($opcao=="Cadastrar"){
    $nome=$_POST["nome"];
    $valor=$_POST["valor"];
    cadastraProduto($nome,$valor);
    header("Location: paginaInicial.php");
}
    else if($opcao=="Alterar"){
        $codigo=$_POST["codigo"];
        $nome=$_POST["nome"];
        $valor=$_POST["valor"];
        alterarProduto($codigo, $nome, $valor);
        header("Location: visualizarProduto.php");
    }
    else if($opcao=="Excluir"){
        $codigo=$_POST["codigo"];
        excluirProduto($codigo);
        header("Location: visualizarProduto.php");
    }
```

Esse é o arquivo que contem as funções. "crudProduto"

```
include 'conexaoBD.php';
function cadastraProduto($nome,$valor){
    conectar();
    query("INSERT INTO produto (nome, valor) VALUES('$nome',$valor)");
    fechar();
}
```

Comment: Sou novo em php. Quando tu diz log de erro, aquele que aparece na página? se for não aparece nada

Comment: Log de erro, o arquivo do servidor onde ficam gravados os erros todos. Uma das primeiras coisas que a pessoa tem que aprender a usar para desenvolver em PHP.

Comment: De qualquer forma, enquanto não sanitizar as strings (e isso depende de qual DB e biblioteca você usa, informação que falta na pergunta) vai dar problema.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/70

Comment: No caso é só um trabalho para faculdade, mas de qualquer maneira estou usando mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A página fica branca porque em `controleProduto.php` você está fazendo declarações de testes condicionais que de acordo com seu código não possuem lógica. Voce está definindo um botão da seguinte maneira:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="opcao" id="Cadastrar">Confirmar</button>
```

No seu arquivo `controleProduto.php` você está verificando se o mesmo possui o atributo `value` igual á `"Cadastrar", "Alterar" e "Excluir"` o que obviamente está incorreto pois no seu `HTML` nem mesmo o atributo `value` do elemento `button` foi definido.